# Tomcat JDBC datasource lookup failing in Spring app

Tags: spring, tomcat

JDBC JNDI lookup started failing on my application after making it Spring aware.

1. JDBC datasource setup on tomcat is correct as the non-spring
   application is able to connect with same setup.
2. Attempted to initiatize JNDIFactoryBean in Application's spring config.

```
    <beans>
    <bean id="myDb" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDb"/>
      <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
      <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

3. Also attempted adding resource-ref in web.xml of the application.

```
 <resource-ref> 
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDb</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope> 
  </resource-ref> 
 </web-app>
```

4. Since publishing this thread, also tried 'jee:jndi-lookup' in spring config.xml.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" id="myDb" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDb"/>
```

---

### JDBC JNDI Datasource Setup

*CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml*

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    ......

    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxIdle="5" maxTotal="25" name="jdbc/myDb" password="ABDC" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://myServer:1233;databaseName=myDBdbdev" username="myUser"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

*CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml*

```
<context>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/myDb" name="jdbc/myDb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    ...

</context>
```

**Error StackTrace**

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/myDb] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].  at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)    at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.abc.myapp.db.DataSourceFactory.createPool(DataSourceFactory.java:126)
>     at com.abc.myapp.db.DataSourceFactory.init(DataSourceFactory.jav

### Code for fetching datasource

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDb");
```

Comment: try `jdbc/myDb` as the jndi name and try setting `resourceRef` to `true` . In your namespace sample you have switched the `id` and `jndi-name` property.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Am confused with the suggestion. Can you please elaborate where I need to change?

Comment: Either. The `jee:jndi-lookup` is basically a nice wrapper around the `JndiTemplate`.

Comment: Ah! That was a typo. For me both the bean declaration or jee:jndi are returning NULL for the datasource.

Comment: They shouldn't return  `null` but rather prevent your application from starting. Also why are you doing a manual lookup instead of using the Spring defined one?

Comment: This was an existing app made spring aware. So have not changed it much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I just found was the below code helps fetch the datasource correctly:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDb")
```

Comment: Which still isn't using Spring. So why on earth are you configurung it in Spring? Don't do a lookup but let Spring inject the dependency ... Basically you have configured spring (and I suspect correctly) but this bypasses all of that completely.